# Decode Private key using passphrase in C#

Tags: c#, nuget, bouncycastle

I have a privateKey which is encrypted using openssl Aes256 algorithm and passphrase.
Passphrase is base64 string

Is there any way to decode the private key in C#. I had searched over internet also found some samples but did not get any result.

Comment: I don't know specifically, but [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93417/what-encryption-is-applied-on-a-key-generated-by-openssl-req) might be a starting point.

Comment: AES-256 has a 256-bit key, as the name suggests. There are many systems for taking your passphrase and turning it into the 256-bit key. You need to find out what system was used with your private key, and then replicate it. How was the key generated: how is it normally decrypted?